# Convert Arabic/Japanese in mySQL to php?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

My mySQL database has foreign characters that are Arabic or Japanese,

تظاهرات در خیابان آذربایجان

and they look perfectly fine in phpMyAdmin (db column structure utf8_general_ci) but when I try to echo them from a mySQL query, I get ???. Since I'm piping this back to an AJAX request, how should I send back the characters so that the encoding comes through?

Thank you from a very confused international student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be either or both of these problems:

Your output encoding is not set right.  Put this in your .php file (near the top, before you send any output):

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Your database connection/communication encoding (not quite sure what to call it) is not set right.  Put this after you connect to the database but before you retrieve any data:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');  // (or equivalent)
```

This ensures that communication between php and mysql is also done in utf8.

Comment: Odd, neither of these seemed to work. The column name is text, so I did SET text utf8

Comment: `SET text utf8` is nonsense.  Do `SET NAMES utf8`.

Comment: Thanks.  I did a lot of searching before I found this post.  This worked perfectly.  Thanks awm!

Comment: @shummel Glad I could help! (A couple of years ago I was pulling my hair out over this...)